# How to sum up complex array formula across rows without storing intermediate results in helper column?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have some "complex" calculation that I currently do row-by-row and store in a helper column. In the end I simply run a `sum` on the helper column to calculate the total value of that calculation.

I would like to simply have one field, where I do the calculation of the total value - without needing the helper column.

To be concrete, I am calculating exertion load (XL): http://www.strongur.io/monitoring-training-stress-with-exertion-load/

As input data I get a weight lifter, repetitions performed and how many reps were in the tank until failure (RIR) is reached. I calculate the XL of a set by expanding the reps performed into a range => 3 reps becomes [1,2,3] and then running an `ArrayFormula` on that range to calculate the distance to failure from the perspective of that rep (rep 1 is further from failure than rep 3) and consequently the XL of that single rep. I then use a `sum` to calculate the total exertion load of the given set.

Unfortunately, this approach does not scale to the "single field"-solution - as I cannot add another `ArrayFormula` around it. I am not sure where to go from here - my spreadsheet experience is limited.

I think I am missing something here from a conceptual perspective - I've been doing some googling and have seen matrices mentioned, would that be the right direction for this kind of thing? I would like to avoid having to write a JavaScript function just for this use-case.

Thanks in advance for any tips/pointers! :)

Best Regards,
Simon

Sample Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CNYxsQKo_CUIsstCDbcjoojL6WK46rg9ONybviFxAGs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: ur formula `SEQUENCE(C2) + D2+SEQUENCE(C2)-1` is not the same as `RIRj+Repsj-i` (as it suppose to..) would u mind sharing y.. ?

Comment: One simple reason: Acute lack of coffee - you are right, that is wrong. I've fixed it, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(B2:B="";;IF(COLUMN(1:1)>C2:C;;
 B2:B*EXP(-0,215*(D2:D+C2:C-COLUMN(1:1)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @player0 thank you very much! Could you explain how this `COLUMN(1:1)` works? I cannot really wrap my head around it - I have the feeling that you are using it to do what I tried to do with the `SEQUENCE`. Would be great if you could explain that :)

Comment: @SimonOswald yes, sequence outputs only one sequence so like in your case we need one sequence per each row... column outputs column number so column(B10) = 2nd column.... column(C5:F100) will output array of 3,4,5,6 and column(2:2) will output all columns present in the row so 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,etc. so what we do here is we use simple if column number is more than value in B column do nothing else use that column number to create (mimic) sequence per each row

Comment: Very neat! Thank you very much for taking the time to look into this :)

Comment: u should click on the 'tick' to mark the question as answered.. ( :

Comment: I'll jump in here and add one thing. If the number of reps per set will ever be more than the number of columns currently in the sheet, `COLUMN(1:1)` will not work. For instance, if rep count is 30 and your number of columns is only 26, you'll wind up with an inaccurate result for that row and thus for the total. You can exchange both instances of `COLUMS(1:1)` with a `SEQUENCE` that is more than the max number of reps per set you'll ever have, e.g., `SEQUENCE(1;50)`.

Comment: @SimonOswald yes, Erik Tyler is right. fix would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBalc.png or: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1C2g.png

Comment: I must have missed the "checkmark" - I've added it now :) 

I think a `SEQUENCE(1;50)` is what I'm going to use - even now I have A-AL, so room for more reps than I'd ever want to do. 50 reps is definetly enough! Thanks to all of you for looking into this :)